# Reference for lowest order complexity of sparse symmetric matrix premultiplying full vector

Tags: complexity-theory, sparse-matrix, symmetric

In a paper I'm writing I make use of an n x n matrix multiplying a dense vector of dimension n. In its natural form, this matrix has O(n^2) space complexity and the multiplication takes time O(n^2).

However, it is known that the matrix is symmetric, and has zero values along its diagonal. The matrix is also highly sparse: the majority of non-diagonal entries are zero.

Could anyone link me to an algorithm/paper/data structure which uses a sparse symmetric matrix representation to approach O(nlogn) or maybe even O(n), in cases of high sparsity?

Comment: To be perfectly clear: the matrix is sparse and the vector is dense, correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would have a look at the [csparse](http://www.cise.ufl.edu/research/sparse/) library by Tim Davis. There's also a corresponding book that describes a whole range of sparse matrix algorithms.

In the sparse case the `A*x` operation can be made to run in `O(|A|)` complexity - i.e. linear in the number of non-zero elements in the matrix.

Comment: Thanks Darren, that's very pragmatic advice :)

Answer (score 1):

Are you interested in parallel algorithms of this sort
http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~scandal/cacm/node9.html